# Gridster widgets appearing vertically in django webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, gridster

In my app which uses django I am displaying gridster widgets.When I run the HTML/Javascript page directly the widgets are arranged as written in HTML code.But when I use same webpage in my django app by placing it in template and keeping static files(gridster.js and some css) in corresponding folders all the widgets just load in a single line

Following is my HTML Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo &raquo; Add Delete Widget &raquo; gridster.js</title>
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/demo.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'js/jquery.gridster.min.css' %}">
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.gridster.min.js' %}" 
type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Add and Remove Widget Dynamically</h1>

<p>When you remove a widget,the widget below it will always remain in the 
same column.Widget from next column wont come in place of widget 
removed.Gridster is designed that way</p>
<a href="https://github.com/ducksboard/gridster.js/issues/338" 
target="_blank"> Click to know more</a>


<div class="gridster">
    <ul>
        <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"><button 
class="delete-button" style="float: right;">-</button><h3>1</h3></li>
        <li data-row="1" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"><button 
class="delete-button" style="float: right;">-</button><h3>2</h3></li>
        <li data-row="1" data-col="3" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"><button 
class="delete-button" style="float: right;">-</button><h3>3</h3></li>
        <li data-row="1" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"><button 
class="delete-button" style="float: right;">-</button><h3>4</h3></li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"><button 
class="delete-button" style="float: right;">-</button><h3>5</h3></li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"><button 
class="delete-button" style="float: right;">-</button><h3>6</h3></li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="3" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"><button 
class="delete-button" style="float: right;">-</button><h3>7</h3></li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"><button 
class="delete-button" style="float: right;">-</button><h3>8</h3></li>
        <li data-row="3" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"><button 
class="delete-button" style="float: right;">-</button><h3>9</h3></li>
        <li data-row="3" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"><button 
class="delete-button" style="float: right;">-</button><h3>10</h3></li>
        <li data-row="3" data-col="3" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"><button 
class="delete-button" style="float: right;">-</button><h3>11</h3></li>
        <li data-row="3" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"><button 
class="delete-button" style="float: right;">-</button><h3>12</h3></li>
</div>


<button class="add-button" style="float:top;">Add Widget</button>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    var gridster;

        gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
            widget_base_dimensions: [100, 100],
            widget_margins: [5, 5],
            helper: 'clone'
        }).data('gridster');



$(document).on( "click",".delete-button", function() {
    var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');
    gridster.remove_widget($(this).parent());
});



$(document).on( "click",".add-button", function() {
var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');      
gridster.add_widget('<li><button class="delete-button" style="float: 
right;">-</button><h3></h3></li>',1,1);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is in my template folder in my django project and when I run it normally in browser(by replacing the css and js path in head section) it runs perfectly fine.

My url.py is somewhat like this

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'gridster', views.gridster, name='gridster'),
]
```

And my views.py is like this

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
from django.http import HttpResponse

from os import path

from .models import Test, IntermediateFile
from .forms import IntermediateFileForm


 def gridster(request):

 return render(request, 'myapp/gridster.html')
```

Note that in views.py I have imported many other modules that I require for some other purpose may be not relevant to this problem

Comment: what is actually your question here?

Comment: The layout of widgets is always vertical in single line in django app(Column 1: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)  but when I run just the html file they appear as expected (Row 1:1,2,3,4) (Row 2:5,6,7,8) etc